# Why can't solutions to Autonomous ODE intersect?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ be continuously differentiable.  Why can't solutions to $x'=f(x) $ intersect?

I use a proof by contradiction:

Assume solutions can, and do intersect at the point $(t_0,y_0)$.  Then, the IVP $ x'=f(x)\quad x(t_0)=y_0$ does not have a unique solution.

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, it is Lipschitz on any interval containing $t_0$.

Thus, by Picard's Existence Theorem, a unique solution exists, which contradicts our assumption.

How does this proof look?  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Specifically,  solutions of a given IVP of the form can't intersect, so you need to add to the question "Why can't solutions $x'=f(x)$ with initial condition $f(t_0)=x_0$