# general solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Consider the homogeneous first-order linear differential equation(DE), $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=0,$$ where $P(x)$ is continuous on an interval $I=(a,b)$. I'm trying to convince myself that its general solution on $I$ is $ce^{-\int P(x)dx}.$  My arguments are given below.  I'll appreciate it if someone can confirm or refute it, or provide a simpler/better proof.

---

First of all, let's divide the solutions of the DE into two types.  Type 1: $y(x)\ne 0$ for any $x\in I.$ And we call the rest of the solutions Type 2.

**For Type 1 solutions**, $y\ne 0$, so the DE is equivalent to:

$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=-P(x),$$

which can be solved by

$$\int \frac{1}{y}dy=-\int P(x)dx.$$

So the general Type 1 solution is $ce^{-\int P(x)dx}, c\ne 0.$ (Note that indeed $y\ne 0$ for any $x\in I.$)

**Regarding Type 2 solutions**, first note that the constant solution $y=0$ is clearly a Type 2 solution.  Furthermore, we show it's the only Type 2 solution, by an argument similar to the one in [why can't a non-constant solution of an autonomous DE intersect an equilibrium solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3007411/235690):

Suppose $y(x)$ is a Type 2 solution with $y(\alpha)=0$ for some $\alpha\in I.$ Then by the existence and uniqueness theorem, $y(x)=0$  on $(\alpha-h, \alpha+h)\subset I$ for some $h>0.$ Let $\beta=\sup\{t: t\le b, y(t)=0, x\in (\alpha-h, t)\}$.  Now suppose $\beta<b$.  Then $y(\beta) \ne 0$, by definition and the existence and uniqueness theorem.  But this means $y$ is discontinuous at $\beta$, contradicting the fact that $y$ has to be continuous. So we must have $\beta=b,$ and $y(x)=0$ for $x\in (\alpha-h, b)$.  By the same token, we can show $y(x)=0$ for $x\in (a, \alpha+h)$ too.

---

Is this argument correct?  Is there a simpler proof?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach: Multiply the equation by the 'integrating factor' $e^{\int P(x)\, dx}$. The equation becomes $(ye^{\int P(x)\, dx})'=0$ so $ye^{\int P(x)\, dx}=c$ for some constant $c$. This gives all possible solutions of the DE.

Comment: That's indeed much simpler.  Thanks a lot!